# Textbox cumulatively added placement the value

Tags: c#, textbox

I want to ask a question. I am getting the data from database and when I write the texbox I want to add nearby entries under the textbox. Like searching on google. Sorry if there is any answer in forum. I don't know how i can search it on google.

Comment: So you're looking for a ListBox, not a TextBox.

Comment: If it works with ListBox. Yes it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want an AutoComplete textbox

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/auto-complete-box-in-wpf-toolkit/

Comment: Exactly I want. It works fine.